# var versus function, which is better for constants and methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, variables, methods

This is in a nodejs application and may also become a chrome packaged app.  Which of the following is better to use for setting constants and methods to use within the application?

```
// HARDWARE SETTINGS AND SCALING FACTORS \\
function GPIO8() {
  this.sensorType     = "I/O board";
  this.name           = "XYZ Co. 8 Channel USB GPIO Module";
  this.info           = "GPIO, 10 bit, 0-5V ADC (Analog to Digital Converter)";
  this.voltSupply     = 5.15; // Measure with multimeter and set this constant.
  this.vMin           = 0;    // lowest output voltage.
  this.vMax           = 1023; // highest output voltage. (10bit = 2^10)
  this.scalingFactor  = function ( ) {
                          return this.voltSupply / (this.vMax - this.vMin);
                        };
  this.voltScaled     = function (adcReading) {
                          return parseFloat(adcReading, 10) * this.scalingFactor();
                        };
}
```

or this?

```
// HARDWARE SETTINGS AND SCALING FACTORS \\
var GPIO8 = {
  sensorType     : "I/O board",
  name           : "XYZ Co. 8 Channel USB GPIO Module",
  info           : "GPIO, 10 bit, 0-5V ADC (Analog to Digital Converter)",
  voltSupply     : 5.15, // Measure with multimeter and set this constant.
  vMin           : 0,    // lowest output voltage.
  vMax           : 1023, // highest output voltage (10bit = 2^10)
  scalingFactor  : function ( ) {
                    return this.voltSupply / (this.vMax - this.vMin);
                    },
  voltScaled     : function (adcReading) {
                    return parseFloat(adcReading, 10) * this.scalingFactor();
                    }
}
```

Both work in the application.
We have 10 different pieces of hardware to setup each with different ranges, scaling factors, and methods.  The other hardware each have a few more constants.  The above is the most simple. Before I setup the other 9, I want to get started correctly.

I read that they are both objects and var versus function does not really matter.  I am not a pro js coder.  Which is the preferred methodology for this specific usage?  (too subjective a question?)

Secondly, are scalingFactor( ) and voltScaled(...) better as methods within these objects or as separate functions outside of the objects.  (I hope I am getting the terminology correct.)

Answer (score 1):

The function is more handy if you're going to be creating multiple objects of the same type. This is classic object orientation. If you're going to have multiple `GPIO8` objects, you can call `new GPIO8(/* some specific settings */)`, and then set the prototype of the object with various methods that will be common across all `GPIO8` objects.

However, in your case, it looks like `GPIO8` will be the only one of its type, therefore literal object notation (the second example you showed) is probably fine.

If I were you, I might spend some time investigating JavaScript inheritance, i.e. [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype). Then you can decide whether `GPIO8` may belong to another class, etc.

## TL;DR: function notation will be helpful if you need a "factory" of similar objects

Comment: Wow.  Fast answer.  I will probably not have more than 1 instance of each object.  Therefore as you note, var is likely better.